# How to display json list object in angular? "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"

Tags: json, angular, rest, object, angular8

I'm trying to show my json data in the table but I got a error "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed". I can see my **json object on the console** with console.log

I got this error when I call **getAll()** my student json list

> StudentComponent.html:24 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object
>   Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

-

> student.ts

export class Student {

```
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  parentId: string;

}
```

> student.component.html

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>parentId</th>

              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let s of student ">
                <td>{{s.id}}</td>
                <td>{{s.name}}</td>
                <td>{{s.email}}</td>
                <td>{{s.parentId}}</td>
              </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

> student.componen.ts

```
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {

  student: Student[]=[];

  constructor(private studentService: StudentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.studentService.getAll().subscribe(res => {      this.student =  res;   console.log(res); });
  }
```

> StudentService

```
export class StudentService {

  private STUDENT_PATH = '/students';

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  }


  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.apiService.get(this.STUDENT_PATH).pipe(map(
      res => {
        if (res) {
          return res;
        } else {
          console.log(res);
          return {};
        }
      }
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your API returns an array of objects?

Comment: What is the response from your API? Print in the console and add it here. Probably its returning a `{}`, instead of a `[]`.

Comment: Try `this.student =  res.data;`

Answer (score 0):

```
{data: Array(20)}
data: Array(20)
0: {id: "b898ccd0-e0ac-4f5a-9727-3af14888fe0c", name: "Brandy Cooke", email: "brandycooke@codeshake.io", parentId: "8d7a6e1b-9373-4d65-bb11-34420704d3bb"}
1: {id: "255067f4-fd23-4fa2-a05e-222764917563", name: "Rose Mitchell", email: "rosemitchell@codeshake.io", parentId: "3190c1c2-a7ff-4f48-87a0-84efa4ad7930"}
2: {id: "dae28df8-365d-4e88-b865-302225924aa8", name: "Gwen Gilbert", email: "gwengilbert@codeshake.io", parentId: "d6e34d2f-7e01-4d7e-b7b1-ad774e1b9911"}
3: {id: "e33a04af-2bc0-4500-a332-52a414a8e6f9", name: "Cooley Farrell", email: "cooleyfarrell@codeshake.io", parentId: "5ffdbbcd-e214-4a35-9d09-7d7003dcdc78"}
4: {id: "97a68161-8e21-4f0f-a2a8-e7d5c492605a", name: "Patti Ayala", email: "pattiayala@codeshake.io", parentId: "77ce908d-eb6e-4b77-b6dd-77a2d25662f4"}
5: {id: "a0f1c667-d8f4-4d3f-9902-90588573b1b9", name: "Stacy Carpenter", email: "stacycarpenter@codeshake.io", parentId: "77ce908d-eb6e-4b77-b6dd-77a2d25662f4"}
6: {id: "7e6e380d-95ce-45ee-9a88-f0152100586d", name: "Hewitt Gregory", email: "hewittgregory@codeshake.io", parentId: "a596261b-7529-4a60-a707-fa89d95b1ef9"}
7: {id: "9dcb017f-f3b0-4118-9d7f-7fa92228adfa", name: "Hobbs Ashley", email: "hobbsashley@codeshake.io", parentId: "20855ec7-900e-4a50-ba41-9885649c1dca"}
8: {id: "37d215b3-0b4f-4549-9ada-3dc6a70c3768", name: "Hollie Franks", email: "holliefranks@codeshake.io", parentId: "5ffdbbcd-e214-4a35-9d09-7d7003dcdc78"}
9: {id: "a4ccb46b-95d9-408d-9fee-423c93462143", name: "Stuart Young", email: "stuartyoung@codeshake.io", parentId: "8d7a6e1b-9373-4d65-bb11-34420704d3bb"}
10: {id: "984b55a3-3b39-4501-8e99-b3d02b3d210b", name: "Ortega Moses", email: "ortegamoses@codeshake.io", parentId: "5ffdbbcd-e214-4a35-9d09-7d7003dcdc78"}
11: {id: "e0f215e4-6277-46e9-8dd4-8fc1b6dca060", name: "Sexton French", email: "sextonfrench@codeshake.io", parentId: "e1919ff2-b547-46ed-b111-3bf1fa26bafc"}
12: {id: "c5022024-80d9-42f3-892c-e9469ae0e37a", name: "Jackson Delacruz", email: "jacksondelacruz@codeshake.io", parentId: "2e8e85b9-ea70-4e95-a305-b5200d00f103"}
13: {id: "13f1a2eb-f87b-4c6a-ac4c-82c6b0a74d9e", name: "Marylou Dickerson", email: "maryloudickerson@codeshake.io", parentId: "5ffdbbcd-e214-4a35-9d09-7d7003dcdc78"}
14: {id: "79bb7076-955b-4c9e-a779-330322caffa0", name: "Teri Watkins", email: "teriwatkins@codeshake.io", parentId: "20855ec7-900e-4a50-ba41-9885649c1dca"}
15: {id: "77eeed93-2c70-4e9c-8380-963e43f8a51d", name: "Robert Osborn", email: "robertosborn@codeshake.io", parentId: "a596261b-7529-4a60-a707-fa89d95b1ef9"}
16: {id: "5836db92-e42b-4f8c-bff3-062cc846360c", name: "Levine Wynn", email: "levinewynn@codeshake.io", parentId: "77ce908d-eb6e-4b77-b6dd-77a2d25662f4"}
17: {id: "dbd1445c-83c9-4958-886c-a9805bcf1392", name: "Maldonado Whitney", email: "maldonadowhitney@codeshake.io", parentId: "e1919ff2-b547-46ed-b111-3bf1fa26bafc"}
18: {id: "bed37c2b-998d-461d-ae67-ebf4f6c01866", name: "Parsons Hensley", email: "parsonshensley@codeshake.io", parentId: "3828a00d-ba5f-43b4-8ef2-f98f463b9972"}
19: {id: "1e28d4bf-56b5-46c0-8010-1d1e98b77cac", name: "Myra Reese", email: "myrareese@codeshake.io", parentId: "d6e34d2f-7e01-4d7e-b7b1-ad774e1b9911"}
length: 20
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

**I can see it on the console**